# Integrating p-values (or z-scores) with missing values

Tags: r, p-value, combining-p-values

I would like to apply a Stouffer (or Fisher) integration on a list of p-values or z-scores. However, some of them contain missing values, e.g. (R snippet):

```
a <- c(0.05,NA,0.04)
b <- c(0.03,0.13,0.01)
```

What is in your opinion the best approach, in order to make the integrations of a and b comparable?

1. Simply remove NA data and calculate. Both Fisher and Stouffer methods take into consideration the number of values to integrate
2. Consider the NA data as "not significant" (sounds like a bad solution)

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: The best approach is dependent on both the magnitude and mechanism of missing p-values. That is, how many p-values do you have in total, and what proportion are missing? More importantly, WHY are some of those p-values missing? Is there any plausible reason that null tests are more likely to be missing than non-null tests? If you have reason to believe the missing values are suitably random in nature, and there are relatively few of them, ignoring them is justifiable. I'm not so sure about 2), although IIRC Fisher's method is overly sensitive to null p-values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are prepared to make suitable assumptions about the missing values there are two methods you could consider. Zaykin and colleagues in an article entitles "Truncated Product Method for Combining $P$-Values" available [here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/gepi.0042) suggest a variant of Fisher's method which truncates all $p$-values above a threshold. So if you can assume that all your missing were greater than some value you can truncate any you have actual values for which fall above that threshold and proceed. This is available in R in the package [Tfisher](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=TFisher).

Alternatively if you are willing to assume that the missing values are missing at random and so could be drawn from a uniform distribution in (0,1) then van Assen and colleagues in an article entitled "Meta-Analysis Using Effect Size Distributions of Only Statistically Significant Studies" available [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25401773) have discussed this in their p-uniform method. They have provided this in an R package [puniform](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=puniform) although you would need effect sizes as well for this.

Comment: 4 years later, an excellent answer. Thank you!